# Conditional behaviour with $(window).width

Tags: jquery

I'd like a certain mouseenter and mouseleave behavior when the window is above 1278 pixels. For widths below 1278, I want to disable this toggle behavior and just set the 2 elements to 1 state (visible & active). I also have to reset the state back to default (hidden & inactive) if the browser is made wider than 1278. This is what I have:

```
$('section').live('mouseenter', function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 1278) {
    $(this).find('menu').removeClass('hidden');
    $(this).find('div.section-wrapper').addClass('active');
  }
}).live('mouseleave', function() {
  if ($(window).width() > 1278) {
    $(this).find('menu').addClass('hidden');
    $(this).find('div.section-wrapper').removeClass('active');
  }
});

$(document).ready(function() {
  $(window).bind('load resize orientationchange', function(){
    if ($(window).width() < 1278) {
      $('section').find('menu').removeClass('hidden');
      $('section').find('div.section-wrapper').addClass('active');
    } else {
      $('section').find('menu').addClass('hidden');
      $('section').find('div.section-wrapper').removeClass('active');
    }
  });
});
```

It works but I'm wondering if I can do something more graceful.

Comment: "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use .on() to attach event handlers. Users of older versions of jQuery should use .delegate() in preference to .live()."  http://api.jquery.com/live/  and finally, you might consider http://codereview.stackexchange.com for questions on improving currently working code.

Comment: This can be done with media queries.

Comment: Note that `on` is not the same as `live`. You still have to delegate events out in `on`. If you use the same syntax as `live` with `on` future elements will not be handled. For example, this is the `on` equivalent of the `live` in this example: `$('body').on('mouseenter','section',function(){...});`. There would need to be another definition for the leave event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CSS media queries are the best option here. Though you won't notice the improved performance unless you're on a slow device, this is the faster equivalent:

```
@media(min-width: 1279px) {
  section:hover {
    menu.hidden {
      display: block;
      visibility: visible;
    }
    .section-container { padding: 14px; }
    .section-wrapper { border: 1px #ddd solid; }
  }
}
@media(min-width: 768px) and (max-width: 1278px) {
  menu.hidden {
    display: block;
    visibility: visible;
  }
  .section-container { padding: 14px; }
  .section-wrapper { border: 1px #ddd solid; }
}
```

The two blocks look almost identical, but they aren't. They force the "active" look upon hovering as well as when the screen is below 1278px wide but above 768px wide.