# Is it possible to add <a> element below 768px resolution?

Tags: javascript, html, css, responsive-design

**The basic question:**

Is there a way to add an hyperlink to a text inside a table to users (below 768px, iPad, iPhone)?

Like:

```
<td>Lorem Ipsum</td>
```

But then, below 768px I want to add this:

```
<td>"<a href="#">"Lorem Ipsum"</a>"</td>
```

Is that possible?

Comment: Have you tried `max-width: 768px; overflow-x: ellipsis`?

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery for it?

Comment: Have a look at [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14287299/conditional-behaviour-with-window-width) and its answer.

Comment: What you're are looking for are CSS media queries.  You can write a CSS rule to hide an element when specific conditions are met (such as screen resolution).

Comment: I know, I'm using media queries, I know what is it (LOL). But I didn't remember of creating another <a> with duplicated text and then hide the other one when resolution is below 768px.

Thank you!
Luís.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A simple way would be:

```
 <td><span class="visible-pc">Lorem Ipsum</span>
     <span class="visible-sm">"<a href="#">"Lorem Ipsum"</a>"</span>
 </td>
```

Where `.visible-pc` is `display:none` if the resolution is < 768px, and same with `.visible-sm` but if > 768px:

```
.visible-pc { display: block; }
.visible-sm { display: none;  }

@media screen and (max-width: 768px) {
    .visible-pc { display: none;  }
    .visible-sm { display: block; }
}
```

---

Another way would be to add the link in Javascript if you detect a clientWidth < 768px, but this is a bit more complicated (you have to play with the DOM, beh.)

Comment: For completeness: you can check the dimensions with CSS using [media queries](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries).

Comment: Hi, this is right way. Adding 2 equal elements and then hide one of them.
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If I understand what you are asking correctly, you want a link to only show up for users of tablets? There are many ways you could go about this. You could use javascript to determine the screen resolution or you could use CSS media queries.

I would recommend looking at responsive layout frameworks. Twitter's "Bootstrap" is an example of one, but there are many more to choose from! Bootstrap has CSS classes to only show content on tablets.

Comment: There is no indication that an entire framework is necessary here.  Just a simple media query rule for now is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
<td><span class="d-text">Lorem Ipsum</span></td>
<td><span class="t-text">"<a href="#">"Lorem Ipsum"</a>"</span></td>
```

css

```
.d-text {
    display: block;
}

.t-text {
    display: none;
 }


@media only screen and (max-width: 768px), only screen and (max-device-width: 768px) {

    .t-text {
        display: block;
     }

    .d-text {
        display: none;
    }


}
```